# Columns in from one table is only Required

Tags: sql

I have written the below and noticed that it is bringing back all the columns from both tables **OrderItems** and *Order* where I only want all the columns from the **OrderItem** table.

```
`SELECT * FROM [OrderItem] oi INNER JOIN
 [Order] o
 ON o.[pkOrderID] = oi.[fkOrderID]
 WHERE [dReceievedDate] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate;`
```

There is a one to many relationship from the Order table to the OrderItem table, so any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: Just select the columns you want instead of `select *`.

Comment: You could do oi.* instead of *

Comment: if you only need the columns from OrderItem, then a join to  Order might be an overkill if you are only checking existence. I take that dReceivedDate is on table order.

Comment: On a side note: SQL is generally not a case sensitive language. So dReceievedDate is the same as dreCeieveDDate. It is common to write column names in lower case (dreceieveddate). To get this readable, we often use the underscore character: d_receieved_date. This ensures readability even if some tool reformats your query. Then, what is d in dreceieveddate for? Supposing that you are just trying to indicate some data type, dont. Just name the column receieved_date. I wouldn't use prefixes pk and fk either. If you just call this order_id, it is obvious that this is the ID of the order table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `select oi.*` or better name all columns that you want to select (`select oi.fkorderid, oi.item_no, ...`). But why join `order` at all, when you don't want to see its data? Use `IN` or `EXISTS` instead:

```
select *
from orderitem oi
where fkorderid in 
(
  select pkorderid
  from [order] o
  where dreceieveddate between @startdate and @enddate
);
```